# snakeyaml-1.27-android.jar not found error while running tests

Tags: java, faker, snakeyaml

./gradlew test

> Task :compileTestJava FAILED
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
> Could not find snakeyaml-1.27-android.jar (org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.27).
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.27/snakeyaml-1.27-android.jar
```

I get the above error with the following definition in my build.gradle file, trying to exclude from javafaker doesn't help either. What should I do here?

```
// faker
testImplementation('com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2')
testImplementation group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.27'
```

Comment: There is an issue in java faker repository with an workaround - https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/issues/327 you gonna need to exclude org.yaml from your javafaker dependency

Comment: @mac this doesn't help, resulting in the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to exclude the org.yaml from the java faker dependency.

```
 implementation ('com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2') { exclude module: 'org.yaml' }
    implementation group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.26'
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I just deleted *snakeyaml* dependencies directory manually (*/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml), it works.

Answer (score 7):

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker
implementation 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2'
```

Result: Could not find `snakeyaml-1.30-android.jar (org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.30).`
Searched in the following locations:
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.30/snakeyaml-1.30-android.jar

Solution: Use `dataFaker` instead of `javaFaker` that will resolve all the issues, like so:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.datafaker/datafaker
implementation 'net.datafaker:datafaker:1.5.0'
```

Comment: Thank you! I solve my problem by using your solution.

Comment: Did it for me. Datafaker states "This library is a improved port of JavaFaker"

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Copy existing snakeyaml jar to the filename being searched

cp /Users/user/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.27/snakeyaml-1.27.jar /Users/user/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.27/snakeyaml-1.27-android.jar

Comment: generic: `cp -p  ~/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.29/snakeyaml-1.29.jar ~/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.29/snakeyaml-1.29-android.jar`